# How to decide which datanode to run my Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Which class I need to override, so that I can decide that jobs with same job Id goes to the core of same system(i.e. Datanode)?

I am a bit new to Hadoop stack, so probably this is too easy to do, but I didn't find any thing sodil on internet around this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your hadoop version?

Comment: Can anyone please answer this, Or please just provide some link...